# XML which have 0x04 in the data

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, google-chrome, xml-parsing

I have lot of xml files which have 0x04 in the data of the file.

Internet Explorer is able to open it while chrome doesn't support it

The xml specification says it as a restricted character

RestrictedChar     ::=      [#x1-#x8]

The character is 0x04 which falls in this category.

How to use the character in xml

Comment: Files that contain `0x4` characters are by definition not XML files — even if they are named `.xml` and otherwise look like XML. If control the process that creates those files, fix it (i.e. use a tool that was made for creating XML, like a DOM API, instead of concatenating strings that also contain some angle brackets). On the other hand, if you have no influence over those files then you can't use them with XML tools.

Answer (score 1):

> How to use the character in xml

You can't. End of story.

Use a binary-to-string encoding like Base64 in order to transport arbitrary binary data in XML.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it, provided (a) you write the character as a numeric character reference, e.g. `&#x04;` (b) you say version="1.1" in your XML declaration, and (c) you use an XML parser that supports XML 1.1. If you're parsing XML in the browser, the chances are that your parser doesn't support XML 1.1.